How to interpret "unresolved exception with suggestion" in Pyspark
Cannot understand this unresolved exception error
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `1_1473_C17_18979` cannot be resolved.

thrown by Pyspark when i apply this thresholding mechanism:
threshold = df.where('step = 4') \
    .groupBy('ID') \
    .agg(F.percentile_approx('event_time', 0.25)) \
    .collect()
threshold = [(r[0],r[1]) for r in threshold]

whereStmt = 'step=1 or step=2 or step=3'

for r in threshold:
    whereStmt = whereStmt + f' or (step=4 and ID={r[0]} and event_time<={r[1]})'
df.where(F.expr(whereStmt))


step and event_time are other columns names.
The string 1_1473_C17_18979 belongs to a ID column, so i'm not entirely free to modify those values. Unless they are reversible transformations.
At the moment my cleaning routine looks like this:
tempList = [] 
# Replacing dashes, dots and spaces with underscores in columns names
for col in df.columns:
    new_name = col.strip()
    new_name = "".join(new_name.split())
    new_name = new_name.replace('-','_') 
    new_name = new_name.replace('.','_') 
    new_name = new_name.replace(' ','_') 
    tempList.append(new_name) 

df = df.toDF(*tempList) 

# Cast values to string, just to bs sure
df.withColumn('ID',df['ID'].cast('string'))

#Replacing dashes, dots and spaces in the column to which the value that appears to generate the error belongs
df = df.withColumn('ID', regexp_replace('ID', '-', '_'))
df = df.withColumn('ID', regexp_replace('ID', '.', '_'))
df = df.withColumn('ID', regexp_replace('ID', ' ', ''))

I tried:

(using code from this thread) catching dashes dots and spaces in columns names (not effective);
replacing dashes and spaces with underscores in values of 'ID' column.

The above error arrives after those transformations.
Without applying the cleaning routine i get this different error:
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `1473_C17` cannot be resolved.

And i'm pretty sure, looking at this part of the same error message:
Filter (((((((((((step#152176 = 1) OR (step#152176 = 2)) OR (step#152176 = 3)) OR (((((step#152176 = 4) AND (ID#152204 = ((1 - '1473_C17) - 17130)))
That the confusion in due to the dashes. That's why i replaced them, etc.
It would be very useful to know the position of the value generating the error as well.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
